# Objective C "Bad URL" error

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection

I am trying to set up an Http GET request to a certain URL from my Objective C code. No matter what I do, or which URL I use, I get the following error:

```
Connection Failed: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain 
Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x755c440 
{NSUnderlyingError=0x7561950 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}
```

I am new to iOS development, so I am not sure if I am doing this right. I have followed the apple documentation and looked for answers in various forums and even then I get this error.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://example.com/api/%@/%@", str1, str2];

NSString *encodedUrl = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"URL - %@", encodedUrl);              // Checking the url

NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];


[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encodedUrl]
                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                      timeoutInterval:10.0];

NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

Any suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: Perhaps you should show us what the log of `encodedUrl` looks like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not initializing your `theRequest`.
This line does nothing if you're not assigning its return value to a variable.

```
[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encodedUrl]
                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                      timeoutInterval:10.0];
```

This is the code you should use:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://example.com/api/%@/%@", str1, str2];

NSString *encodedUrl = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"URL - %@", encodedUrl);              // Checking the url

NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest= [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encodedUrl]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:10.0];

NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

Comment: @RameezHussain if you got your solution then why don't you accept this answer. so that your question is closed..